# Windows size script

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var w = $(window).width();
if (w >= 320 && w <= 480) {
  $(".projects").slice(1, 8).css("margin", "10px");
} else {

    $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");

};
```

How can I make this work when window size is changed, not only when loading the page?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.resize`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function to catch the event:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');

$(window).resize(function() {
   var w = $(window).width();
   if (w >= 320 && w <= 480) {
      $(".projects").slice(1, 8).css("margin", "10px");
   } else {
      $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
   };
});
```

Comment: You need to set `w` inside the function.

Comment: With this copy paste not display slice 3,6 why? that the default?

Comment: Probably your window size is more than 320 wide and lower 480 height.

Comment: 1009px this not display $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");

Comment: I believe the above code will run only when the window is resized. If you want it to also run when the page first loads you could add `$(window).trigger('resize')` afterwards, or declare the function as a variable and just call it directly after binding it to `$(window).resize()`

Comment: Yes, that's true Matt. @user3327101 Try with my updated code.

Comment: :( not working not understand because windows resize function there...?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with this code but maybe these fiddles can help you, http://jsfiddle.net/5gsLS/3/ (code) and http://jsfiddle.net/5gsLS/3/embedded/result/ (result)